# Create points inside polygon based on attribute in QGIS

Tags: qgis, point, attribute-table

I have a polygon layer with population and I need to create a new point layer based on that polygon layer.

The polygon layer has an attribute with the specific number of people living in each polygon.

How do I create X points (where X is the absolute number of people based on the attribute information) inside the boundaries of each polygon?

Comment: Thank you poellinf. One question: when using "Random Points" you have to specify the Input Boundary Layer. Does it mean that the random points will be distributed randomly across the layer or they will be created inside each polygon based on the input field? I mean, my polygon layer has more than 100 polygons representing neighborhoods and each one of this 100 polygons have a specific number of inhabitants. If I use the random points tool, will I get X points in polygon A and Y points in polygon B or they will be distributed across the layer boundary (A+B...+N)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the 'Random Points' function in 'Vector' -> 'Research Tools'.
Select your Input Layer anch check 'Use value from input field'.
[image]
Your input field has to a numeric.